# Spring boot relaxed bindings

Tags: spring, spring-boot, environment-variables, spring-integration, properties-file

I am trying to understand relaxed bindings in Spring boot
I have looked at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding
but I think I am missing something
If I have a properties file a.properties that contains a.b.c=123 and I want to use an env variable to override it then I believe I should be able to add A_B_C=456 and it should work, but it does not seem to be doing that.
Am I just completely missing something

#### EDIT

I guess the real question is, Can I use the RelaxedDataBinder with the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to do relaxed bindings?

Answer (score 1):

So after researching and chatting with individuals this is not directly possible.  The simplest solution to get this moving forward, I believe, is to create an annotated bean in the spring-boot app that defines the properties and uses @ConfigurationProperties to then initialize the values.  This should use the relaxed bindings at this point. I can then use this bean instead of property placeholders to build the spring integration beans.

Thanks to @dsyer for the suggestion.